# Global Vue variable is undefined in components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, signalr

I am implementing SignalR in ASP.NET Core in my vuejs front end. In order to do this I need a global variable to access these events in my components but for some reason the dashboardHub variable shows undefined in console. Am I declaring them incorrectly on my vue instance?

```
    <script>//setup routing using SPA VUE interface
    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    const routes = [
        { path: '/', component: dashboard },
    ]

    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes, // short for `routes: routes`
    })

    console.log('Signalr mounted', window['signalR']); // output : Undefined 
    var signalR = window.signalR;
    try {
        this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(window.location.origin + '/dashboardHub', {})
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .build();
        console.log('Signalr Connection', connection);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('SignalR error ', error)
    }

    // use new Vue instance as an event bus
    const dashboardHub = new Vue()
    // every component will use this.$questionHub to access the event bus
    Vue.prototype.$dashboardHub = dashboardHub
    // Forward server side SignalR events through $questionHub, where components will listen to them
    connection.on('UpdateDashboard', () => {
        dashboardHub.$emit('review-movement-hub')
    })

    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify({
            options: {
                customProperties: true
            },
            theme: {
                themes: {
                    light: {
                        primary: '#6237A0',
                        secondary: '#9754CB',
                        alternatePrimary: '#7cb6b1',
                        accent: '#DEACF5',
                        textaccent: '#28104E',
                        background: '#f7f7f7',
                        error: '#b71c1c',
                    },
                },
            },
        }),
        router,
        data() {
            return {
                flexcontainer: {
                    'display': 'flex'
                },
                flexchild: {
                    'min-width': '0',
                    'flex': '1 1 auto',
                }
            }
        }

    }).$mount('#app')
</script>
```

I use the dashboard variable in my dashboard components as follows:

```
            created() {
            console.log(this.dashboardHub)
            // Listen to score changes coming from SignalR events
            this.dashboardHub.$on('review-movement-hub', this.test)
        },
```

However in the console.log it comes back as undefined but I did define it in the declaration section of my vue instance as shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you defined the variable as:

```
Vue.prototype.$dashboardHub = dashboardHub
```

Then you access it with the dollar prefix from the Vue instance

```
created() {
    this.$dashboardHub.$on('review-movement-hub', this.test)
},
```

Comment: This does the trick but oddly enough it does not seem like that connection I create is still open as now event is being emitted. I do know on the backend it is working as intended. And on the front end it does show those console connections starting but not sure if they close when that script is finish running.

Comment: In your code there is a mix of comments mentioning `$questionHub` when in your code you use `$dashboardHub`, but I don't see your component code so I'm not sure if that's relevant. I also don't know what you mean by closing the connection, so I can't help you without more info.

Comment: Understandable and yea those are just example comments from code of a tutorial I am following. Your answer though is what I needed originally so I will accept it. Thanks!